# pyspark dataframe to json with root element

Tags: json, pyspark, databricks

I have created a valid json output from a dataframe using this code:

```
json = fullDataset.select(to_json(struct(col("*"))).alias("json"))\
.groupBy(spark_partition_id())\
.agg(collect_list("json").alias("records"))\
.select(col("records").cast("string"))
```

which give me an output of

```
{"records":"[{\"alias\":\"ForeignExchange\",\"HourUTC\":\"2021-10-24T22:00:00.000Z\",\"MunicipalityNo\":201}, {\"alias\":\"ForeignExchange\",\"HourUTC\":\"2021-03-02T13:00:00.000Z\",\"MunicipalityNo\":390}
```

However I have not figured out how to add root elements.

Desired output:

```
{
    "resource_id": "7f615ff3-af7c-4ab3-ba33-998bf017b5a3",
    "method": "upsert",
    "force": "test",
    "records": "[{\"alias\":\"ForeignExchange\",\"HourUTC\":\"2021-10-24T22:00:00.000Z\",\"MunicipalityNo\":201}, {\"alias\":\"ForeignExchange\",\"HourUTC\":\"2021-03-02T13:00:00.000Z\",\"MunicipalityNo\":390}]"
}
```

Comment: you're selecting only `records` in the last line. Add more columns if necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the other columns that you want to bring as parameters in the `select` function call.

```py
json = (
  fullDataset.select(to_json(struct(col("*"))).alias("json"))
  .groupBy(spark_partition_id())
  .agg(collect_list("json").alias("records"))
  .select(col("resource_id"), col("method"), col("force"), col("records").cast("string"))
)
```